# Database archive strategy

Tags: database, database-design, archive

We have oracle database having 10 yrs of data. We want to archive them as application is getting slow due to large sets of data. Issue is that system still needs to access old data if user wants. So how can we design that? For example if we archive the data from 2010 to 2015 in archive database and delete the data from the current database, application will query based on a date to some table which has a data range and then connect to appropriate database i,e current or archive. There is also a possibility to get all the data from both databases in some cases.

[How to archive records in multiple tables within one access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28347710/how-to-archive-records-in-multiple-tables-within-one-access-database)

Above solution talks about archiving but i need to have strategy if user wants to access the old records.

Thanks